# How to solve error 403 while using the discord library in python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am getting an error while executing the following code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.message_content = True


peoples = [
    {'Name': 'Artem', 'id': 'steamid:1234'},
    {'Name': 'Sergey', 'id': 'steamid:1434'},
    {'Name': 'Bogdan', 'id': 'steamid:1534'}
]

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/', intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {bot.user.name}')

@bot.command()
async def accept(ctx, value: str):
    id_v = None
    print(value)
    print(f"Command 'accept' invoked by {ctx.author.name} ({ctx.author.id}) with argument {value}")

    for i in peoples:
        print(i['id'])
        if i['id'] == value:
            id_v = i
            print(id_v['id'])
            break

    if id_v is not None:
        new_nickname = str(id_v['Name'])
        print(new_nickname)
        await ctx.author.edit(nick=new_nickname)
        await ctx.send(f"{new_nickname} принято ✅")
        print(f"Nickname updated for {ctx.author.name}")

    else:
        await ctx.send(f"Значение {value} не найдено в списке.")

# Replace 'YOUR_BOT_TOKEN' with your actual bot token
token = ''

# Run the bot
bot.run(token)
```

I am getting this error on line 244:

```
in wrapped raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

Maybe this is a line with a nickname change, but the bot has administrator functions enabled, so I don't even know what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

Even with administrator permissions enabled, the bot can still have insufficient permissions to change someone's nickname if the bot has a role that is "lower" than the role of the member you're trying to modify. If you are going to use it, there's no other method than dragging the "Bot" role to the highest in the role hierarchy, higher than every other role including "Owner".

The following is an example role hierarchy.

```
| Roles
  | Bot (higher than Owner, Head Admin, etc so I can change the nicknames of all of them, etc let them enjoy my service)
  | Owner
  | Head Admin
  | Moderator
  | Verified
  | @everyone
```

Please keep in mind that putting the bot higher than all roles could end up being a serious security issue if you do not configure your bot correctly or leak the token.

Answer (score 0):

I decided everything, there was an error due to the fact that I requested a nickname change from the bot to myself (that is, the main administrator)

Answer (score 0):

How to create a library of names for a user

```
            thread = await ctx.channel.create_thread(
            name="принято ✅",
            type=ChannelType.public_thread
        )
        await thread.send(f"Вам выдана <@&1189799283055132723>")
```